# Reformatting rows

Tags: awk, sed

I have several rows that look something like this,

```
[206, 40, 200] 3.588939213064659e-06
[206, 40, 58, 200] 1.0137134449402395e-05
[206, 200] 1.2268187790002155e-05
[206, 38, 200] 3.2630262623982875e-05
[206, 40, 38, 200] 3.273281423485983e-05
[206, 40, 58, 38, 200] 3.341643719910475e-05
```

Is there an efficient way I could convert them to the following using sed/awk,

```
206 40 200
206 40 58 200
206 200
206 38 200
206 40 38 200 
206 40 58 38 200
```

and this,

```
206 40 200 0.000003588939213064659
206 40 58 200 0.000010137134449402395
206 200 0.000012268187790002155
206 38 200 0.000032630262623982875
206 40 38 200 0.00003273281423485983
206 40 58 38 200 0.00003341643719910475
```

Thanks!

Comment: With sed, the first is easy, the second practically impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the latter requirement, please try:

```
awk '
{
    split($0, a, "] +")
    gsub("[[,]", "", a[1])
    printf("%s %.21f\n", a[1], a[2])
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a regex Field Separator and format conversion to variable.

```
$ awk -F'[][, ]+' '$NF=sprintf("%.21f",$NF)' file
```

*edit:* The easy one is `awk -F'[][, ]+' '{$NF=""}1'`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/\[.*\]/){val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);gsub(","," ",val);print val}'  Input_file
```

For your second question could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/\[.*\]/){val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);gsub(","," ",val);printf("%s %.21f\n",val,$NF)}'  Input_file
```